# Неправильно вычисляется остаток

Tags: excel, vba, visual-basic, макросы

Написал макрос, который должен был выводить на третий столбец необходимое к заказу количество товара (Эталон - минимальное количество товара, Остаток - количество товара, которое есть в магазине. Если Остаток меньше Эталона, то в отдельный столбец должно выводиться количество товара, которого не хватает магазину). Проблема в том, что выводятся совершенно ошибочные значения.

```
Dim Etalon As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant, Ostatok As Variant, d As Variant
Set Ostatok = Range("B2:B660")
Set Etalon = Range("C2:C660")
        For Each x In Ostatok
        For Each y In Etalon
            If x < y Then
                d = y - x
                x.Offset(0, 2) = d
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Ну, судя по коду, в магазине всего один товар... что, не так? а где выполняется сверка наименований?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле перебираются ячейки Остатка (`x`) и во вложенном цикле сравниваются с каждой ячейкой Эталона (`y`). Уже на этом этапе возможна ошибка, так как явно не указано, что сравнивются значения. (`x.Value < y.Value`). Да, по умолчанию программа должна понять, что это значение, но всякое бывает...

Здесь, как я понимаю, ошибка в другом. Обычно один товар - одна строка. Значит, и проверять значения нужно построчно, а не сравнивать остаток одного товара с эталонными значениями всех товаров.

```
Sub Order1()
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set rData = Range("B2:E660")

    For i = 1 To rData.Rows.Count
        If rData(i, 1).Value < rData(i, 2).Value Then
            rData(i, 4).Value = rData(i, 2).Value - rData(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

    Set rData = Nothing
End Sub
```

На большой таблице такой код будет работать медленно, лучше перейти на работу с массивом. Да и длину диапазона можно опрелделить по столбцу `B`

```
Sub Order2()
    Dim aData(), aResult()
    Dim i As Long

    i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    aData = Range("B2:C" & i).Value
    ReDim aResult(1 To UBound(aData), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To UBound(aData)
        If aData(i, 1) < aData(i, 2) Then
            aResult(i, 1) = aData(i, 2) - aData(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    Range("E2").Resize(UBound(aResult), 1).Value = aResult
End Sub
```